# Practices for Optimizing Css For Opera-Mini Browser

Tags: android, html, css, optimization, opera

I know that opera tunnels our resources through its servers and gives users compressed data.

Here are two websites that I visited using Opera-Mini(Android)

1. **Github** - [Github Screenshot](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/1/?view=att&th=1557810d117b4fad&attid=0.2&disp=inline&realattid=1537839627613765632-local1&safe=1&zw&saddbat=ANGjdJ9RrTcl7qr-A_xNpOFyQyVxehloyxRRXHXioYEmVF_C5Tjmp3S2LTT2XlhLfvfhKiXyew4kJ_6KttG7bFaMlVOSjM9RYbkNqDoBBigFXL8Xl2hFUICrGEM8JunsgHYC3YYMyQSAgRl-U5ENpuNnekfo57lbNswozTnO8YfH1PACnQ1vtGwM1lDoG7sVu46ri0x_UcV64Ytk5O12i_RISemBGKC91l1NciztKHRMxtNV14FVgFE-XaVjwXSSXBVL0QMPTYZJbibj9SGDw8yEJT10XLWn0V6I9rfd1kX_LtBm68Dca3ol99UrDfXgG4HvJO6Uz9yPMjcPYCrjtixL8YvQZo5xPT8oYvGzRmou8YT512c6wYWc77sZ00cN5xZJkeiEKi0P8SMQ_VD1BB6EH-UF1Tdq963bq7WcQlo32DKWgomVwpqvYi26o9mVyFWmG34s5zwAnHAdKe2fq0vR7CScCSC3XhlHVIjBs8JiuSNiIeB0swgqcdJ3H8sg-m--5AIKy7mUKUPhxA46I8TfB5kykGr1pOmcOsMLAc2Vq9hTY_7hI1LNKaRz1ZROeI7aXNSLIt37SGSaS7SNklEeJiv43aKQe8Zih-v-JaGq9hJ1iupwqXCjFBacYfTiIFMIhbAawglg8jk0T1A0)
     The buttons are looking irregular(not padded). Ugly borders around buttons/input boxes. Divs are not properly-positioned. Font are all simmilar sizes. Uses default fallback font. Images are low-sized(svg/png) are HQ. Images overlap Hyperlinks.
2. **Amazon** - [Amazon Screenshot](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/1/?view=att&th=1557810d117b4fad&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=1537839627613765632-local0&safe=1&zw&saddbat=ANGjdJ_sbOFJgVRbcG5PXrHQUoWURFmW4ZG6eff0ZzacBKOcLzGyfRIAbmR3WWOl3qzk9EkOO2gQ5_OQJ7CBTDk4zZeYgKmcmGgKko1QTXjknwQNo_ksHu4nfkjgpmPhdj04_E-RV5BJLMHrZjvgFSYqcG_Ke2ZWjeGdj4RoC0MCL57Jqp0N1O6DpZOZQQ4g4aR4N1oSQV-MTBZIXVloYabFui8_F0_HETOzeSW6blOHqBU7BkPI7HJ4n-hV3pAoP2O_txbcXcGhPgAX8bLJMeb6QN7hZts7ow1bLzZEX_4WTw4Y5Gd0ULpHdMHBdcR3bCm_CwTgWuYEy8f869Emo-RLZIS1kQWZytsaqZToyPjLhSs0kctAXPv8IjOHiqlxF2OlbaPluNftK98ZpltWZOhccA_TNFr-OEVMBVdj5kohF1PiZVuSISNfuMpvCGYgtT6KXlQgoQ3pNamSGd87dAIN6ebP9ohH3DqAO_iUU9clwkpPHrgYqbiqO_VfhgL0s6PSVxFNJqHpXvGxc_GwiQRNZDclSCf91IuROnKsZkaNIgAKLANHSk2ukLRf5gO9I1_wkt9vx3zspbO_I6xqM1YRENMB442FO5_TUcfhhaAiFowDhOetTRjkBWUQ0i-5KBK0HN3PhRCqRzM-N-Ub) 
   Beautiful Borders. Font-Family looks different. Font-weight and font-size are also proper(and different). Divs are floated and aligned in proper way. Images(svg/png) are HQ.Images not overlapping Hyperlinks.

**P.S** *Both the sites look good in Mobile Chrome.*

Most of the sites look like (1) in Opera-Mini.
And Few other shopping sites(ebay etc) looks proper optimized even in Opera-Mini.

So basically I want to know the tricks-practices of css on how Amazon,eBay manages to design their site looking so good even in those kind of mobile browsers.

Also my media-queries are not working in Opera-Mini ( but are beautiful looking in Mobile Chrome)

```
@media(max-width:480px){
    #somerule{
               //not working
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give high-level advice since your question is high-level as well.

Go to caniuse.com and look up well supported HTML4/CSS2.1 tags/attributes. Those are mostly the ones you need to stick to when writing CSS compliant for Opera Mini and its ilk.

Another tip is to always test your website in Opera Mini when you make any change, to ensure compliance. Best way to do that is to install the Opera Mini Emulator on your system, and use `ngrok` to tunnel your localhost. Technical details are nicely documented [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/installing-opera-mini-on-your-computer/).

Lastly, I would advise you to read [this](https://dev.opera.com/articles/making-sites-work-opera-mini/) pretty conclusive article by [Bruce Lawson](https://dev.opera.com/authors/bruce-lawson/). He touches upon media-queries as well.

It's going to take some trial and error, but you'll get there if you're persistent.